# FileSystemNotFoundException on dependency with spring boot 3.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependencies

i recently tried to update from spring-boot 3.1.6 to 3.2.0 and ran into the following problem:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
at ai.picovoice.porcupine.Porcupine$Builder.build(Porcupine.java:242)
...
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: null
at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:156)
at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getPath(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:142)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:209)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:98)
at ai.picovoice.porcupine.Utils.getResourceDirectory(Utils.java:58)
at ai.picovoice.porcupine.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:39)
... 28 common frames omitted
```

I tried to figure out where the dependency tries to do this and found something like this:

```
  private static Path getResourceDirectory() throws RuntimeException {
    URL resourceURL = Porcupine.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();

    Path resourcePath;
    try {
      resourcePath = Paths.get(resourceURL.toURI());
    } catch (URISyntaxException var4) {
      resourcePath = Paths.get(resourceURL.getPath());
    }

    if (resourcePath.toString().endsWith(".jar")) {
      try {
        resourcePath = extractResources(resourcePath);
      } catch (IOException var3) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to extract resources from Porcupine jar.");
      }
    }

    return resourcePath.resolve("porcupine");
  }

  private static Path extractResources(Path jarPath) throws IOException {
    String extractionDirName = jarPath.getFileName().toString().replace(".jar", "");
    String systemTempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    Path resourceDirectoryPath = (new File(systemTempDir, extractionDirName)).toPath();
    if (!Files.exists(resourceDirectoryPath, new LinkOption[0])) {
      try {
        Files.createDirectory(resourceDirectoryPath);
      } catch (IOException var13) {
        logger.severe("Failed to create extraction directory at " + jarPath.toString());
        var13.printStackTrace();
        resourceDirectoryPath = (new File(systemTempDir)).toPath();
      }
    }

    JarFile jf = new JarFile(jarPath.toFile());
    Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jf.entries();

    while(entries.hasMoreElements()) {
      JarEntry jarEntry = (JarEntry)entries.nextElement();
      String jarEntryName = jarEntry.getName();
      if (jarEntryName.startsWith("porcupine")) {
        Path dstPath;
        if (jarEntry.isDirectory()) {
          dstPath = resourceDirectoryPath.resolve(jarEntryName);
          if (!dstPath.toFile().exists()) {
            Files.createDirectory(dstPath);
          }
        } else {
          dstPath = resourceDirectoryPath.resolve(jarEntryName);
          InputStream is = jf.getInputStream(jarEntry);

          try {
            Files.copy(is, dstPath, new CopyOption[]{StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING});
          } catch (Throwable var14) {
            if (is != null) {
              try {
                is.close();
              } catch (Throwable var12) {
                var14.addSuppressed(var12);
              }
            }

            throw var14;
          }

          if (is != null) {
            is.close();
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return resourceDirectoryPath;
  }
```

I already unpacked the dependency like so (in 3.1.6 it worked):

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>net.indexoutofmj.neptune.NeptuneBot</mainClass>
                    <requiresUnpack>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>ai.picovoice</groupId>
                            <artifactId>picovoice-java</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </requiresUnpack>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

but it seems to fail now ... and i don't know why

Can somebody help ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, when `resourceURL.toURI()` throws a `URISyntaxException`, it is also possible that `resourceURL.getPath()` returns `null`. I suppose, this could happen with frameworks packaging jars inside jars. Besides that, who writes `(new File(systemTempDir, extractionDirName)).toPath()` instead of a straight-forward `Paths.get(systemTempDir, extractionDirName)`?

Comment: That could be possible, but i'm still wondering why unpacking the dependency won't work anymore

Comment: Try logging the `resourceURL` If you can’t modify this method, you can check the result of the expression `Porcupine.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` anywhere where the class `Porcupine` is accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it was a bug in spring boot 3.2.0, since 3.2.1 it works as it should